# ReactNative, Android run error: Could not determine java version from '11.0.1'. Windows 10

Tags: java, android, reactjs, react-native, gradle

Java version: **11.0.1**
React Native version: 0.57.5
React Native CLI version: 2.0.1

**Android device is connected and given access, tuned on debug via USB**

When I run **neact-native run android** I get this following error:

Starting JS server... Building and installing the app on the device (cd android && gradlew.bat installDebug)...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Could not determine java version from '11.0.1'.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
  Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
  Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
  set up your Android development environment:
  https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You seem to be using an older version of Gradle, from 4.8+ your project should build

The below directory `gradle/` is in whichever directory `gradlew` or `gradlew.bat` is in.

- Edit the file called `gradle-wrapper.properties` located in `./path-to-project-root/gradle/wrapper`
- Replace `distributionUrl:...` with the following

`distributionUrl=http\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.0-bin.zip`

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue. I update the gradle version to gradle-4.8-all.zip in the following file in disributionUrl:

[your-react-native-project]/android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties

It solved the issue.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I had the exact same issue. It works for me to update the gradle version to "gradle-4.8-all.zip".
By the way it didn't work for me to use the gradle version "gradle-5.0-bin.zip".

Comment: same with me too. It gave some react errors. Maybe 5.0 is too new for react :)